# When carrying out spatial point pattern analysis on my point files I get an error for standard distance

Tags: point, analysis

How to fix an error with standard distance in spatial point pattern analysis. When performing spatial point pattern analysis QGIS 3.4 is only carrying out the mean point calculation correctly and there is an error for the standard distance calculation. I am using EPSG 29902 (Irish National Grid) How do I get this to work.

See below for error.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The `BHGull standard distance` file has a strange extension (`.prj.shp`). Try fixing it so it can be recognized as a regular shapefile

Comment: How do I change the file? The input filed  is a BHGull.shp file that I enter into the spatial point pattern analysis. Then the process saves the output BHGull mean file correctly as BHGull Mean.shp but is not able to make the BHGull standard distance shape file incorrectly and instead gives an output file as BHGull standard distance.prj or BHGull standard distance.prj.shp.?